# How to solve crossword (NP-Hard)?

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem, greedy, np-hard, crossword

I am currently doing an assignment and I'm stuck with the approach.

I have a crossword problem which consists of an empty grid (no solid square as a conventional crossword would), with a varied width and height between 4 and 400 (inclusive).

**Rules:**

1. Words are part of the input - a list of 10 - 1000 (inclusive) English words of varying lengths.
2. A horizontal word can only intersect a vertical word.
3. A vertical word can only intersect a horizontal word.
4. A word can only intersect 1 or 2 other words.
5. Each letter is worth one point.
6. Words must have a 1 grid space gap surrounding it unless it is a part of an intersecting word.

**Example:**

```
X X X X X X  
X B O S S X  
X X X X X X
```

**Goal:**
Get the maximum possible score within a 5 minute time limit.

**So far:**
After some research I am aware that this is an NP-Hard problem. Thus the most optimal solution cannot be calculated because every combination cannot be examined.

The easiest solution would appear to be to sort the words according to length and inserting the highest scoring words for maximum score (greedy algorithm).

I’ve also been told a recursive tree with the nodes consisting of alternative equally scoring word insertions and the knapsack algorithm apply to this problem (not sure what the implementation would look like).

**Questions:**

1. What allows me to check the maximum number of combinations within a 5 minute time span that scales accordingly to the maximum possible word list and grid size?
2. What heuristics might I apply when inserting words?

Btw the goal here is to get the best possible solution in 5 minutes.
To clarify each letter of a valid word is worth 1 point, thus a 5 letter word is worth 5 points.

Thanks in advance I have been reading a lot of mathematical notation on crossword research papers all day which has seem to have lead me in a circle.

Comment: "Thus the most optimal solution cannot be calculated because every combination cannot be examined" – surely you are using a word list to feed it with? Then the number of possible solutions is finite. (This may include "no solution found".) Although depending on the length of your word list it may take longer than 5 minutes.

Comment: There is indeed a fed in word list.

Comment: A words score is equal to the amount letters in the word thus a 5 letter word is worth 5 points. I did actually say this "each letter is worth 1 point".

Comment: @Sienks: Ah, you did too -- sorry, poor reading comprehension on my part.  Feel free to roll back your edit.

Comment: I am not sure that `sort the words according to length and inserting the highest scoring words for maximum score` is a good idea. I would actually start with the shortest ones (more options of placing more words). Remember, maximum of 2 intersections. Also, what about finding the most common letter?

Comment: Is your goal to find the only that gives maximum score or just get as much points as you can in five minutes?

Comment: The best possible (highest scoring) solution in 5 minutes.

Comment: This really seems to be an interesting problem. Did you see it in some online forum or something?

Comment: This is 1 part of an assignment I'm currently doing. Im trying to use this as an opportunity to push myself to come up with a good solution (not just some simple greedy algorithm off the top of my head).

Comment: Actually, to come up with solutions for such problems, you need to just think of a basic strategy, apply it and then see how it is doing. Then you further improve it or if it is really bad, you think of a new one.

Comment: I've worked on many such problems (which are similar to coding bot for a game) and the toughest thing is how to design your heuristics that measure the performance. It calls for some discussion and time. I'd write a very basic  strategy in an answer, but all improvization on it is something you will need to do.

Comment: Does a letter at an intersection count as 1 or 2 points?

Comment: Every character worth 1 point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start with a word with following characteristics:

- It should have max possible intersections.
- Its length should be such that number of words of that length are minimum in the list.

ie, word length should be least frequent and most number of intersections.
Reason for this kind of selection is that it would minimize further possibility of words that can be selected. eg. A word of size 9 with 2 further intersections is selected. These intersecting words are of length 6 and 5 (say). Now, you have removed possibility of all those words of length 6 and 5 whose 3rd char is 'a' and 2nd char is 's' (say, 'a' and 's' are the intersecting letters). 

If there are many places with same configuration, run this selection procedure one or two steps deeper to get a better selection of which part (word) of the grid to fill first.

Now, try filling in all words in this 1st selected position (since this had min frequency, it should be good to use) and then going deeper in the crossword to fill it. Whichever word results in most points till a deadend is reached, should be your solution. When you reach a dead-end, you can start over with a new word.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a really interesting problem in discrete optimization. You're certainly right; with the number of words and number of possible placements there is no way you could ever explore a fraction of the space.

Also given the 5 minute time limit (quite short), I think you're going to have a really hard time with any solid heuristic. I think your best bet might be some sort of random permutation / simulated annealing algorithm.

If I was doing this, I would first calculate clusters of words, completely ignoring the crossword structure itself. Take one word, find a second word that intersects it. Then find another word that can fit onto this structure (obeying the max of 2 intersections per word), and so on. You should end up with many of these clusters, which you can rank by density (points / area used). I think you should be able to do this relatively quickly.

Then for the random permutation / simulated annealing part, for my moves I would place either a cluster or unused word onto the crossword itself, or move an existing cluster / word. Just save the current highest-scoring configuration as you go, and return this after the 5 minutes.

If the 5 min is too short to find anything meaningful using random permutations, another approach might be to use a constraint propagation idea working with those clusters.

Comment: If you just ignore the structure of crossword and start making clusters as such, there will be many many clusters, which would be really hard to store first of all and you say that it can be computed quickly. How do you suggest such clusters be computed? I think that making such clusters would take a really really long time.

Comment: Because, say, a word of length 7 has 2 `e's` at position 2 and 7. Since `e` is most occurring character, there would be about 300 words (at least, in a collection of 1000 words) having `e` in some position. Which words do you suggest to put in now? Also, with these 2 `e's`, let this 1st word have an `a` and an `s`, then how do you suggest he selects 2 points of intersection?

Comment: My instincts would be to use a recursive algorithm to build these clusters. Pick one word (probably the longest). Pick a second word (probably 2nd longest). For each possible insertion point, start a new recursion adding a 3rd word, and so on. Go until you hit a dead end; you now have a cluster. I may very well be wrong that calculating this will take far too long and use far too much memory. But a quick heuristic might be worth while, as I think these clusters would be valuable to have for the problem.